# javascript works in Chrome and Firefox But not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some JQuery and JavaScript code that works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE.  The code is nested inside of SAS and I removed the SAS nesting.  Does anyone see a reason why this code would error out in IE?   related.  I am using IE 11.  I am getting the error: document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );

---

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function saveMultiSelection(pageName) {
    document.getElementById('save_degStudLevComma').value  = $(""#degStudLev"").multipleSelect('getSelects');
    document.getElementById('save_studyLevelComma').value  = $(""#studyLevel"").multipleSelect('getSelects');
    document.getElementById('save_sumLevComma').value  = $(""#sumlev"").multipleSelect('getSelects');
    document.getElementById('save_awardTypeComma').value  =  $(""#awardType"").multipleSelect('getSelects');
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can comment on the answers of your own question. Please don't use answer space for comments!

Comment: David, you should really [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), before going any further. You need to know how this site works, instead of posting comments in random places.

Comment: It looks like this is blowing up inside of the jquery call.  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );  Does this mean that the Jquery library that I am referencing needs to edited?

Comment: I’m increasingly thinking this is a SAS compatibility issue.  I’m using a Jquery plugin from: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/
Since the plugin code runs fine on the page in IE 11 and I tried copying the code directly from the page into a SAS stored process, where it errors, there is a low probability of the code directly causing the error without using it in conjunction with SAS.

Comment: I tried the 1x version of Jquery with SAS and it worked.

Comment: Then again i got the same error a click later with 1x and SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use jquery all the way if you have it in your app already?

```
function saveMultiSelection(pageName) {
  //(...)
  $('#save_degStudLevComma').val($("#degStudLev").multipleSelect('getSelects'));
  //(...)    
}
```

Comment: Well, its an assumption as author of thread is writing to value of those elements

Answer (score 0):

You can see broswer support version -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

> IE support = 9+  ->DOMContentLoaded